# Laravel 5.4 - I can't use static array to save data in controller. How to deal with it?

Tags: laravel-5

I want to keep some data from every request but I don't want to use database , because these data just keep temporary , so...I use a static array in my controller,

```
public static $aId = [];
```

and when request come in , I take the data and push it to that array , just like

```
public function saveId(Request $request){
   $id = $request->id;
   array_push(MyController::$aId,$id);
   return var_dump(MyController::$aId);
}
```

But problem is , every request will make that array become a new array , I always get an array which only have one data. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the cache or session would work for you. Create a unique key, such as

`$key = Auth::user()->id . '-aId';`

```
Cache::put($key, $id, Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10));
```

or

```
Session::put($key, $id);
```

and reference that between requests. The user id will not change and the `-aId` suffix will allow you to keep what you have in the session already.

**edit**
ok so you want it globally available across all users, sessions, etc...

```
// assuming an array has already been set in cache key 'request-ids'...
$id = $request->id;
Cache::forever('request-ids', array_push($id,Cache::get('request-ids')));
```

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/is-it-possible-to-share-cache-between-users

Comment: ["43068-aId"]=>
  string(20) "02eWIgcIUJVqVNGNAAAI"
  ["9270-aId"]=>
  string(20) "E2X_wE1PGuhvMiL2AAAP"

Comment: What am I looking at here? Is that two different users you tested?

Comment: I use Chrome and FireFox to visit my website , but different explore can't get another explore id in their session , 

here's chrome all id :
["18942-aId"]=>
  string(20) "nFTS4Vv3f38eAVtKAAAJ"
  ["17816-aId"]=>
  string(20) "T4HVp3bG95F9PQ61AAAK"
  ["10324-aId"]=>
  string(20) "aZ4GvDaB8gZV6whWAAAO"

here's FireFox all id:
 ["43068-aId"]=>
  string(20) "02eWIgcIUJVqVNGNAAAI"
  ["9270-aId"]=>
  string(20) "E2X_wE1PGuhvMiL2AAAP"

How to get all those id without use database??

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what your're trying to achieve here... is this data you're trying to share across all users? Like some kind of global array?

Comment: $id = $request->id;
        $arr = Cache::get("request_ids");
        if(is_null($arr)){
            Cache::forever("request_ids",[]);
        }
        array_push($arr,$id);

        return var_dump($arr);

always return a new array only have one id....it can't save all ids.

Comment: Cache is global. You just need to set the initial array if it's empty in the cache, i.e. the first request to come through, then you will forever have access to the array via the key you set. So let me break it down... if cache is empty for your key, set it with an array. If cache is not empty, read the array from cache, push your id onto the array and put the array in cache with the key.

Comment: OK , $arr is value , not reference , so have to forever again , I got it , thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the session to persist data over multiple requests.

```
public function saveId(Request $request){
   $id = $request->id;
   $request->session()->push('aId', $id');
   return print_r($request->session()->get('aId'), true);
}
```

More information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session

Comment: I can't use session , I need to save those ID for send message to certain user , those id is their socket id , session can't get the id of another user.